# REST pattern create, update and delete same endpoint

Tags: api, rest

I have a page where I list the books of a school. The user can update a book, add a new book or delete an existing book. All actions must be saved when the form is submitted.

How can i map a rest API for that? I could take advantage of the endpoints i already have.

UPDATE

```
PUT /schools/1/books
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Book 1"
    }
  ]
}
```

CREATE

```
POST /schools/1/books
{
  "books": [
    {
      "name": "Book 2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Book 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

DELETE

```
DELETE /schools/1/books
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

But I need everything to run on the same transaction, and wouldn't make sense to submit 3 requests.

I also thought of creating a new endpoint where I would create books that doesn't exists, update books that exists, and remove books that are not present on the request.

So if this school has `Book 1` and `Book 2`, I could update `Book 1`, create `New Book` and remove `Book 2` with:

```
PUT /schools/1/batch-books
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Updated Book 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "New Book"
    }
  ]
}
```

Do you guys have other options?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would separate things into different resources:

- `/books` and `/books/{id}` for books. They gives book details and allow to manage them.
- `/schools` and `/schools/{id}` for schools. They gives school details and allow to manage them.
- `/schools/{id}/books` to associate books in schools. I mean books that are available within a school. This resource provides methods to manage a list of links to books.

Let me detail the last resource. In fact, this is related to hypermedia. In the following, I'll use JSON-LD but you're free to use other hypermedia tools.

A `GET` method will return the list of associated books:

```
GET /schools/1/books
[
  {
    "@id": "http://api.example.com/books/1895638109"
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://api.example.com/books/8371023509"
  }
]
```

You can notice that you can implement mechanisms to allow to get more details if needed. Leveraging the [`Prefer`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) header seems to be a great approach (see the link below for more details).

In addition, you could provide the following methods:

- `POST` to add a link to the school. The request payload would be: `{"@id": "http://api.example.com/books/1895638109"}`. The response should be a 201 status code.
- `DELETE` to delete a specific link from a school. A query parameter could be used to specify which link to remove.
- `PATCH` to allow to do several operations in one call and actually provide some batch processing. You can leverage at this level [JSON-PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) for the request processing. Within the response, you could describe what happens. There is no specification at this level so you're free to use what you want... Here is a sample for the request payload:

  ```
    PATCH /schools/1/books/
    [
      {
        "op": "add", "value": "http://api.example.com/books/1895638109"
      },
      {
        "op": "remove", "path": "http://api.example.com/books/8371023509"
      }
    ]
  ```

Reading the following links could give you some hints on the way to design such use case:

- Implementing bulk updates within RESTful services: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/05/18/implementing-bulk-updates-within-restful-services/
- On choosing a hypermedia type: http://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/
- Creating Client-Optimized Resource Representations in APIs: http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2015/06/25/api-representations-prefer.html

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Awesome, never understood the use case for the PATCH method and now everything is clear. I'll have a look at the resources you posted! Thanks a lot